# for loop suddenly stops C

Tags: c, string, loops, pointers, for-loop

Hey guys I get a really strange thing going on in my for loop.

When I execute this code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
char* repeat(char c, int n);

int main(void)
{
    char* input;
    input = repeat('c', 12);

    return 0;
}

char* repeat(char c, int n)
{
    char* out;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) //FIX ITERATION
    {
        int len = strlen(out);
        out[len] = c;
        out[len+1] = '\0';
    }

    printf("%s\n", out);
    return out;
}
```

I get the expected output:

```
cccccccccccc
```

But when I use the passed int in my method, like this:

```
char* repeat(char c, int n)
{
    char* out;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) //VARIABLE ITERATION
    {
        int len = strlen(out);
        out[len] = c;
        out[len+1] = '\0';
    }

    printf("%s\n", out);
    return out;
}
```

I just get this as output:

```
cccc
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong. I don't have any clue what the error could be?

thank's for helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is the problem

```
  int len = strlen(out);
  out[len] = c;
  out[len+1] = '\0';
```

`out` is not initialized. You did not allocate memory in this statement:

```
char* out;
```

So you are experiencing [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Section 3.4.3

> 1 undefined behavior
>
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous
>   program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International
>   Standard imposes no requirements

Section 4.1:

> An lvalue (3.10) of a
>   non-function, non-array type T can be
>   converted to an rvalue. If T is an
>   incomplete type, a program that
>   necessitates this conversion is
>   ill-formed. If the object to which the
>   lvalue refers is not an object of type
>   T and is not an object of a type
>   derived from T, or **if the object is
>   uninitialized**, a program that
>   necessitates this conversion **has
>   undefined behavior**. If T is a
>   non-class type, the type of the rvalue
>   is the cv-unqualified version of T.
>   Otherwise, the type of the rvalue is
>   T.

In both examples you have shown the result is undefined.

You have to allocate memory:

```
char * out = malloc(sizeof(char)*50); // i have used size 50 - take sufficient what you need
//initialize it 
out[0] = '\0';
```

Make sure to include `stdlib.h`.

`out` now points to a memory block which can hold 50 `char`s.

Comment: Thank you for helping. How would you initialize out in this case. like: char* out = &out[0]? I am pretty new in C.

Comment: @user3025417 The size you provide depends on your requirement - see my edit.

Comment: @user3025417: use a `memset`

Comment: @eckes: indeed you allocated memory for out but you still didn't initialize it - passing out that way to strlen is still not good idea I think

Comment: @user300234: after your `malloc`, you `memset` the fresh `out` with `memset(out, 0, sizeof(char)*50)`. Then, a `strlen` on the empty `out` will return 0 and a `strlen` on a modified out will return a correct value.

Comment: @al-Acme Your solution: char * out = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
//initialize it 
out[0] = '\0'; leads to: implicit declaration of function `int malloc(...)'  initialization to `char *' from `int' lacks a cast

Comment: Ah just remembered [malloc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) returns a `void *` so typecast it to `char *` - see my edit. Also make sure to include `stdlib.h`

Comment: If you use `malloc()` — a reasonable solution to the problem — don't forget to add the appropriate `free()` to release the memory once it is no longer needed.  Otherwise, you have a memory leak, and they're bad in real-life programs.  (In the sample code, there are no harmful consequences to the leak — but embed the `malloc()` call in a loop in a big, long-running program and the leak becomes a big problem very quickly.)

Answer (score 3):

In the function `repeat()`, you don't assign any memory for `out` to point to.  Then you try to return the uninitialized pointer.  That can be OK if you've dynamically allocated the memory, or if you've got it pointing to a static array, or it points to a string literal, but if it points to a local (automatic) array, it is bad news.

Your code is exhibiting undefined behaviour; any behaviour is valid because your code is malformed.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* out;
```

is never initialized so using uninitialized variables lead to UB

You are using the uninitialized variable `out` in `strlen(out)`

The pointer `out` should point to some valid memory location .

```
char *out = malloc(size);
```

Comment: That gives me: warning: implicit declaration of function `int malloc(...)'
warning: initialization to `char *' from `int' lacks a cast

Comment: @user3025417 `int malloc()`?